# What is the best way to deal with exception in step 1 when step 2 is must to execute

Tags: java, exception

In our application situation is, user has requested to update 2 fields say (A, B) for an account.
An account has multiple stores to which updated fields to be pushed. One of the store is marked as default store.
Field A has some validations to be done for default store (say limit on quantity.).

> If validation fails I am throwing exception.
>   On success field value is added to store_space_table

Field B must be pushed to all stores. Pushing to store can throw exception when that store is down or unreachalbe. 
Currently I have written this code in finally block.

I don't want to rollback the first operation on the exception in the second step. Rather I want to consolidate the exception of step 1 and step 2 and propagate that.

```
void validateFieldAndPushToStore(List<Field> inputFieldList, Account account) throws ServiceException {

    List<Store> allStoresOfAccount = getAllStoresOfAccount(account);
    Set<Store> storeListToPushData = new HashSet<>();

    try{
        if(ifFieldAUpdated(inputFieldList)) {
            // get default store from list of stores of an account, 
            Store defaultStore = getDefaultStore(allStoresOfAccount)

            // Validate space availability of A on default store, if validation is successful, then update data in store_space_table 
            validateSpaceOnDefaultStoreForFieldA(defaultStore);

            storeListToPushData.add(defaultStore);
        }
    } finally {
        if( ifFieldBUpdated(inputFieldList) ) {
            storeListToPushData.addAll(allStoresOfAccount);
        }

        if( ! storeListToPushData.isEmpty()) {
            // This operation reads fields A from DB (store_space_table), reads field B from field_tbl and push to stores.
            pushUpdatesToStores(account, storeListToPushData);
        }
    }
}
```

As I read on multiple forums, such handling in finally is not correct/efficient. So I am looking for alternative or better approach to handle this situation.

Comment: Code aside, what is your intended logic here?  If the first validation passes, but the second one fails, do you want to rollback the first step?

Comment: Your business logic should be in your `try` block. Do all the validation first, then update all your stores. If there are two separate DB updates, then they should be wrapped in a transaction so they both succeed or fail together.

Comment: Need more details on the business logic to be implemented. But as mentioned by @dave, business logic must be in try and validations must be done first.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No, I don't want to rollback the first operation on the exception in the second step. Rather I want to consolidate the exception of step 1 and step 2 and propagate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have 2 operations which are supposed to get executed even if one of the fails and you also want to propagate the exception/error to above layer, following approach can be used-

```
void methodPerformingTwoOperations() throws Exception {
    Exception firstOperationErrror = null;
    Exception secondOperationError = null;

    try {
        performFirstOperation();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        firstOperationError = e;
    }

    try {
        performSecondOperation();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        secondOperationError = e;
    }

    throwExceptionAsPerErrors(firstOperationError, secondOperationError);

}

void throwExceptionAsPerErrors(Exception firstOperationError, Exception secondOperationError) {
    // depending upon exceptions compose and throw new exception from here
}
```

**Update**
Note that when using `@Transactional` always validate what parameters you are passing to this annotation. By default propagation property is set to `REQUIRED` which means all the transactions will run in the same transaction and if exception specified all will be reverted.

If you want to persist data from one operation even if other one fails then you can apply `Transactional` on the inner methods(***but not on the main method***). Please refer to the code from the answer by @alexrolea.

Answer (score 1):

The two updates should be wrapped in a transaction.

`@Transaction` is a nutshell.

Your service should be structured as follows.

```
@Transactional
public void validateFieldAndPushToStore(A a, B b) {

    serviceA.validateAndPushA(a);
    serviceB.validateAndPushB(b);

}
```

Where the implementations for serviceA and serviceB would be.

```
@Transactional
public void validateAndPushA(A a){
    validate(a); // can throw validation exception from here
    persist(a); // can throw persistence exception from here
}

@Transactional
public void validateAndPushB(B b){
    validate(b); // can throw validation exception from here
    persist(b); // can throw persistence exception from here
}
```

Please note the `@Transactional` on top of `validateAndPushA` and `validateAndPushB`.
The `persist` methods should be annotated with `@Transactional` as well.

If you would structure your code in this way, if any validation or persistence exception would occur, **all database changes will be rolled back**. This happens because `@Transactional` has a property called `propagationLevel`, which if left on the default value will execute any inner transaction (for example those of the `persist` operations) in a single outer transaction (i.e. `validateAndPushA`, `validateAndPushB`, `validate` and `persist` will all execute in the same transaction - so any exception thrown by those methods will result in the whole transaction being rollbacked).

`@Transactional` allows for a lot of fine tuning, such as for which exceptions the transaction should not be rolled back. Please consult the documentation for all the details.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is an annotation that exists in Spring and JavaEE, but how do you know that OP uses either of these frameworks? What if it is a Java SE only application?

Comment: I suggested using an out of the box JTA implementation for code reuse purposes. What would stop you from defining your own @Transactional annotation, write your own aspects on top of plain database drivers and use that instead (if you insist on having a Java SE only application)?

Answer (score 0):

Capture the exception instead of using finally:

```
boolean failed = false;
try {

} catch (YourException ex) {
    failed = true;
}

if (failed) {

}
```

If you want the exception to be propagated you can store it an a variable and then re-throw it.